# Get Wordpress dashboard submenu links

Tags: wordpress

How do i get the submenu links from the backend menu?

e.g.  Wordpress has the menu links `Posts, Media, Pages` etc..  I want to diplay the sub menu links somewhere else but i don't know how to fetch them?

Where does wordpress store this information in the database?

For example if i want sub menu links of `posts`, what is returned is the links of `All Posts`,`Add New`,`Categories` & `Tags`.

If this is not possible, i'll just copy and paste the links instead...

Answer (score 1):

It's not stored in the database. It's defined by codes like

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page

You can modify it with your own code

```
<?php

   add_action( 'admin_menu', 'edit_dashboard_menu' );

   function edit_dashboard_menu(
     global $menu;
     global $submenu;

     // alter the data
   }
?>
```